# Export HTML list to pdf using jspdf

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists, jspdf

I'm trying to export a ul li HTML element to pdf with jsPDF, but when I export it I get the text without indentation.

For example, when I try to export:

> - Parent 1
>   - Child 1
> - Parent 2

I get the next pdf

> Parent 1
>   Child 1
>   Parent 2

I'm using to export to pdf, the next function:

```
 function demoFromHTML() {
     var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
     var source = $('#testcase').first();
     var specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
      }
    };

     doc.fromHTML(
        $('#testcase').get(0), // [Refer Exact code tutorial][2]HTML string or DOM elem ref.
         0.5,    // x coord
         0.5,    // y coord
         {
             'width': 7.5, // max width of content on PDF
             'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
         });

     doc.output('dataurl');
}
```

Are there any way to format the text correctly?

Lot of thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you using the latest version? It should work, see http://jsfiddle.net/RbdF8/3/

Comment: Hi diegocr, I have 0.9.0 rc2 version, so I supposed its the latest version. I downloaded it from [link](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf). Thx for your help, finally I solved the problem building the pdf manually, first loop the list and then adding it depending on the depth of the node.

Comment: The current version is 1.0.209 - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF (dist folder)